# Create a Macro that replaces a columns data with the next column over each month of a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that would essentially take a column of data from one cell and replace it with the next cell over every month from a different work sheet. I have attached my recorded Macro of using Find & Replace of what I do to do it now.

```
Sub Update()
    Update Macro

    Range("I6:I38").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="$AC:$AC", Replacement:="$AD:$AD", LookAt:=xlPart _
      , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
      ReplaceFormat:=False 
End Sub
```

The range is on a different worksheet than the `$AC:$AC` and `$AD:$AD`

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I did not get what you want to do. Do you want to replace the cell every month, which means the workbook adapts it self every month with a new worksheet. Or do you have different worksheets for different months and you want to loop through them? Please tell us more about the workbook your working with, what the functionality should be ect.

Comment: The workbook has a worksheet that gets updated each month, and the update is reflected on a summary tab. I want the summary tab to automatically pull from the updated worksheet. Right now, I am doing this manually with a find and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Oke, now i got it:

You need to use the Workbook_SheetChange event. If you do not know how events work, ask google. The Workbook_SheetChange event can be accessed using the VBA Editor (alt+F11). Then you click on your workbook as if it was a module. Then you copy **ALL** of this code into the workbook, save it, close it, reopen it and adjust the ranges as well as to your worksheet names.

Then it should work fine.

```
Option Explicit
Public Enabled As Boolean


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Enabled Then
Enabled = False
Dim summary As Worksheet, Jan As Worksheet, Feb As Worksheet, Mar As Worksheet
Set summary = Worksheets("Summary")
Set Jan = Worksheets("Jan")
Set Feb = Worksheets("Feb")
Set Mar = Worksheets("Mar")

summary.Range("B5").Value = Jan.Range("A1").Value
summary.Range("B6").Value = Feb.Range("A1").Value
summary.Range("B7").Value = Mar.Range("A1").Value
Enabled = True
End If

End Sub
```

There is a global variable Enable which switches the Event Sheetchange of. This is needed, because the Sheetchange function changes a sheet which triggers the function and you get an infinite loop. So with this boolean you will turn this off. The workbook_open event sets the boolean to true so you will start with enabled and turn it temporarely off and on again.

Like this everytime your workbook gets changed your summary will be automatically updated.

good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am not sure this is exactly what I want, sorry for the ambiguity. I have a worksheet that allows me to put in values for each month (revenue, expense, profit). After that it takes a sumif function and puts them to the summary tab as a presentation of Year to date. I want to be able to update the column in the worksheet tab that then will send the new updated sumif function to the summary tab. Right now I am using Find & Replace to do this manually.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to macros too, so I am not great at this.

Comment: no problem, that's what the site is for. Just make sure that you define the problem in such detail, that someone else can reproduce your problem.